# Image saved in sdcard shows only black screen using GPUImageView in android

Tags: android, android-image, android-gpuimageview

I am developing one project which is used to apply some effects on the image which will be selected from gallery or captured through camera.

I have used the [GPUImageView](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/blob/master/library/src/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/GPUImageView.java) library for applying different effects on the images and also implemented the seekbar for increasing and decreasing the effects. Everything is working fine.

The problem is that now i want to save that effects applied image into sdcard. I have written the code for it and its working successfully but the image is saved is remained black. Whenever i check the image from the sdcard it does not show the modified image except black screen.

I do not know why its showing black image.

Here is the code where i have made the `GPUImageView` as drawingcachedenabled to true and saving it as image.

```
mGPUImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = mGPUImageView.getDrawingCache();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath();
File fil = new File(path + "/MyPics");
fil.mkdir();
Random rand = new Random();
int aa = rand.nextInt();
String filename = "Photo" + aa+".jpg";
File newImg = new File(fil, filename);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newImg);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

}
    Toast.makeText(this,"File Saved at Path---->" + newImg.getAbsolutePath(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mGPUImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: You can directly get effects Bitmap from the **GpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied(final Bitmap bitmap)** rather than get it from the SurfaceView..

Comment: `GLSurfaceView` is quite different from a normal `View`. So you can not get contents of `GLSurfaceView` by using `getDrawingcache()` as everything is rendered on `GLSurfaceView` using GPU. and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753519/display-black-screen-while-capture-screenshot-of-glsurfaceview/21756336#21756336) answer may help you...

Comment: Why are you not using `saveToPictures()` method of `GPUImageView.java`?? Is there any problem??

Comment: @user370305 I already tried that but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What are the problems? Did you seen any log from `GPUImageView` in logcat?

Comment: I did not get any issues. But its asking for the Listener `OnPictureSavedListener` implementation and the listener wants Uri of the image Which is not possible to pass for me.

Comment: Ok, call  `public Bitmap getBitmapWithFilterApplied()` this method of `GPUImage.java`. It will return effect applied current bitmap image and using Bitmap Factory store in Sdcard.

Comment: I guess you have added `GPUImage` library source into your project.

Comment: Yes, Its added @user370305

Comment: OK, try my above comment and let me know what happen. Because `GPUImage` Library code tested and working fine.

Comment: But i have used `GPUImageView` not `GPUImage` class.

Comment: @GrIsHu I dont Know how to use GPUImageView but with GPUImage its working fine and easy too..

Comment: @kalyanpvs Please can you show me how you have used it ?

Comment: @GrIsHu ok..wait i will post..

Comment: Thank you all I have resolved my issue by help of @user370305 . Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by using the `saveToPictures()` method of `GPUImageView.java`.
I simply converted the `File newImg` into the `Uri` and passed it to the Listener of `OnPictureSavedListener` class's `onPictureSaved` method as below:

```
        mGPUImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        File fil = new File(path);
        fil.mkdir();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int aa = rand.nextInt();

        mGPUImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
         mGPUImageView.saveToPictures("MyPics", "Photo"+aa+".jpg", picSaveListener);
        picSaveListener.onPictureSaved(Uri.fromFile(newImg)); 

   OnPictureSavedListener picSaveListener = new OnPictureSavedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureSaved(Uri uri) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I want to get bitmap of parent view and parent view contain mGPUImageView. But when I get bitmap from parent view it show only black screen. How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can Create object for `GPUImage` and Apply your filter..

```
    final GPUImage mGpuImage = new GPUImage(getApplicationContext());
    mGpuImage.setFilter(new GPUImageSharpenFilter());//Your filter here
    Bitmap effectsBItamap=mGpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied(your bitmap);
```